# Bumpbox 2.0 and jquery library confliction?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have just installed bumpbox 2.0 and found a confliction with jquery.min.js (v.1.7.2)
Bumpbox will not popup if i am running the jquery library, when i remove the library it works.

I have tried previous versions of jquery.min.js and the problem remains.

Problem is i need the jquery library, so what is the work around?

*I am using bumpbox as it seems to have better swf capability and thats all i need it for

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and this helped me.

```
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".hit").click(function() {
     $('##header').html('<img src="/english/images/myheader.jpg" width="760" height="97" />');
    });
});
doBump('.bx2',850, 400, '000', '000000', 0.7, 7, 2 ,'333', 15,'000', 2, Fx.Transitions.Back.easeOut, Fx.Transitions.linear);
```